Visual Studio Code - code reference break if I use path.join to specify imports (nodejs)
I am trying a more centralized way of specifying the import paths in nodejs, by using core path module.
Problem is that when changing from code A to code B specified below, Visual Studio Code stops recognizing the imports/modules, thus not putting any "link" reference to that specific code in the module.
I understand the reason why: Visual Studio Code "does not know" the result of path.join, and shouldn´t know (at least by default), I just cannot find a way to solve it.
Is it there any configuration in Visual Studio Code I can change to solve this?
== Code A ==
/* References for server, io or app. modules are all OK. For example, I can pick io.initSocketServer method with "CTRL+Space" then selected it from the list */
const path = require('path');
process.env.MY_APP_DIR = path.resolve();

const server = require("./server.js");
const io = require("./socketServer.js");
const app = require('./expressRoutes.js');

io.initSocketServer(server.io);    
app.initWebApp(server.app);

== Code B ==
/* No module references for server, io or app. modules. For example, I need to write io.initSocketServer all by hand, instead of CTRL+SPACE and picking from the list */
const path = require('path');
process.env.MY_APP_DIR = path.resolve();

const server = require(path.join(process.env.MY_APP_DIR,"server.js"));
const io = require(path.join(process.env.MY_APP_DIR,"socketServer.js"));
const app = require(path.join(process.env.MY_APP_DIR,'expressRoutes.js'));

io.initSocketServer(server.io);

app.initWebApp(server.app);

I did try to find any specific parameter in Visual code settings. But didn´t find any related, mainly because I don´t know where or what to look.
